# Combine output of two concurrent programs with bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I want to capture output from two concurrent programs (tails on logfiles) into one output stream in bash.

I used this example program for testing:

```
function foo { for i in $(seq 1 10); do echo "program $*"; sleep 1; done }
```

Now the following works fine

```
(foo bar & foo baz &) | tee /tmp/output
```

but once I add an extra pipe in the mix it no longer works:

```
(foo bar | grep bar & foo baz &) | tee /tmp/output # does't work
```

The output becomes sequential. I could make a separate program that includes the grep but I'd like to know if there is a way around this.

If someone can explain why it doesn't work I would be very happy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Great question! This one had me stumped for a bit but I think I know what's going on. What's happening is that `grep` is buffering the output. So, if you let it run you'll see it all flood at the end. If you happen to be using GNU `grep` try passing the --line-buffered option:

```
(foo bar | grep --line-buffered bar & foo baz &) | tee /tmp/output
```

To hazard a guess, and mind you that's essentially what it is, I'd say that `grep` is buffering more output because `isatty(1)` would indicate that it's *not* writing to a TTY (even though you are watching the output on a TTY via `tee`). By buffering more output it makes fewer `write()` calls, and is more efficient. The familiar behavior of running `grep` and watching the output in a terminal is line buffered -- lines appear as they're found. This option forces `grep` to run in that mode.

Keep in mind, as the man page warns, this could have performance impacts on `grep`.

Comment: "even though it is, because of tee".  grep is *not* writing to a tty.  grep is writing to a pipe, and tee is writing to a tty.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Poor wording on my part -- I'll edit my post to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Because of use of pipe between `foo bar` and `grep` you are making grep to wait for the output of the `foo bar` command and that's why all the lines with `bar` come at once after baz lines. If you really want to grep something from the command then define another function like this:

```
function foo1 { for i in {1..3}; do echo "program $*" | grep "$*"; sleep 1; done }
```

And then execute:

```
(foo1 bar & foo baz &) | tee /tmp/output
```

Now you will notice that output looks like:

```
program baz
program bar
program baz
program bar
program baz
program bar
...
...
```